# Is it possible to fill multi models into the interpreter using tensorflowlite?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I would like to build up a products through two different models by tensorflowlite. For example, voice and data prediction. Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, just create 2 interpreters, one for each model.